# different meaning of words google translate api

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-translate

I have question. I use google translate api and some words e.g. "table" have different meaning. If I translate this world to russian language (using api), I got translate only for one meaning. How I can get several translate for several meaning?

My code:

```
const Translate = require('@google-cloud/translate');
const translate = new Translate({
    keyFilename: 'token.json',
});
const text = 'table';
const target = 'ru';
translate
  .translate(text, target)
  .then(results => {
    console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
    console.log(`Translation: ${JSON.stringify(results)}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

My output:

```
Text: table
Translation: ["Таблица",{"data":{"translations":[{"translatedText":"Таблица","detectedSourceLanguage":"en"}]}}]
```

except the word "Таблица", should be the word "Стол"

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Cloud Translation API's FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions):

> **Is it possible to get multiple translations of a word?**
>
> - No. This feature is only available via the web interface at
>     translate.google.com

So this feature is only available through the web interface at [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com), and therefore there is no way to have multiple translations of the same content using Cloud Translation API.